# Can bootstrapping be used for the case of the violation of independent observations in multiple regression?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, bootstrap, robust

I am fitting linear models with lme4 in R.
Initially, I planned to fit mixed-effects model, but I realized that my data is partially nested; some clusters only have one or two observations (I detailed my issues here: [What are the options I have for partially clustered design, when using Mixed-Effects Model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/322065/what-are-the-options-i-have-for-partially-clustered-design-when-using-mixed-eff?noredirect=1#comment611626_322065)). Because of this unbalanced clustering structure of the data, the mixed effects model I fitted does not provide reasonable estimations. However, if I fit a model without the random effect of the cluster, I am violating the assumption of independent observation.

While looking for ways to cope with this, I heard the method called bootstrapping. It sounds like applicable to this case, but I could not find any articles using bootstrapping to cope with violation of the independent observation assumption. I would really appreciate it if I could hear any information regarding this.

Thank you for your help!